# Year in industry Conundrum

Tags: software-industry, work-experience

I am probably on the wrong exchange and if I am I apologise but this seemed to be the closest one that fits.

I am a 2nd year Computer Science student and I have acquired a years placement at a data solutions company. They deal in large amounts of data using technologies such as NoSQL, C# etc...

Now its only a month away it's all starting to come home and I have second thoughts e.g. leaving my fiancé for a year, loosing my study group, being held back another year etc. All these didn't really cross my mind too much when I was applying for these jobs.

If I was to turn around and say no thank you to the job and carried on straight into year 3 do people feel I would be throwing away a brilliant opportunity.

I am trying to weigh up the pros and cons in a logical way:

- If I did a year in industry would I be seen as someone who has worked for a year and could I apply for say a software engineer job instead of a junior software engineer so theoretically I haven't actually lost a year. Basically would I by pass the initial internship/junior rolls a lot of graduates have to go through with their first job.
- As it would be too late to apply for any summer internships I would leave university without any software specific experience. I have worked 2 years before as a Manager in the service industry. I have also received 80% for my first years mark and have targeted my self 85% this year (I am aware marks don't mean too much in the industry now a days). Would this look horrendous on my CV? I am aware it would damage it but as there are quite a few software jobs due to the industries growth would it really affect it that much?
- Has anyone here done an industrial placement in their second year and feel that they are a lot stronger in their field after it going into their 3rd year? It may seem like a silly and obvious question but as I am loosing my study group I would have to revise and bounce ideas off my self for the final year.

Once again apologises if this is in the wrong section but any advice would go a long way to making sure I made the best decision.

Comment: I would try [this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) as it is a bit more likely to give you advice. General advice types of questions are harder to answer conclusively in a dedicated Q/A format.

Comment: Anyone who tells you that your uni marks are unimportant is a loon. Especially for straight out of uni, it is the only way to guage how good your are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of, if not *the*, biggest difficulties that new entrants to the IT industry face is getting over the "lack of experience" hurdle. For that reason alone, I would personally advise that it is indeed a great opportunity and you shouldn't turn it down without good reason.

That said, a year away isn't going to be easy either and this is certainly a very personal decision. Keeping it on-topic - I doubt it's going to drastically alter the course of your career either way, but it does have the potential to make transitioning from Uni to your first job easier.

Comment: That is very true with the point with the lack of experience hurdle. That is always a concern for me hence why i'm trying to make sure I don't run the risk of leaving my options very limited. Thank you for the advice